# javascript onclick function parameters string with space

Tags: javascript

I have four tabs in my webpage :

the onclick function for About and contact tab works fine as there is no space but for the first 2 the onclick jscript call is not working,
please help.

```
<div id="TopHalf">
<ul id="menu" >
<li><a  id="Donate" onclick=GetClick(\"+'Donate space'+\");>Donate blood</a></li>
<li><a  id="PickUp" onclick=GetClick("PickUp space");>PickUp blood </a></li>
<li><a  id="Contact"    onclick=GetClick("Contact");>Contact</a></li>
<li><a  id="About"  onclick=GetClick("About");  >About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


enter code here
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: replace space with underscore `Donate_blood` ,`PickUp_blood` as well change href of anchor tag on tab accordingly like `#Donate_blood` and `#PickUp_blood` this is just an assumption for be more specific add your code as well

Comment: I don't understand why you successfully put quotes around your `id` attribute value, but somehow failed to do exactly the same for your `onclick` attributes...

Comment: Yes, replacing space with underscore works but this text will be displayed to user in form of tabs where we can't really user underscore

Comment: Don't provide screenshots of text. Provide text. Provide an [mcve]. Preferably provide live demos using the [snippets feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: You had the code in your question - and you just took it out?

Comment: this is tough , can't add screenshots or code ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of either ensuring the attribute quotes don't conflict with the JavaScript string quotes, or by escaping. This should work:

```
onclick="GetClick('Donate blood');"
```

Better still, move away from messy inline events and register them centrally in an external JS file.

HTML

```
<ul class='my_links'> <!-- <== note parent class -->
    <li><a id="Donate">Donate blood</a></li>
    <li><a id="PickUp">PickUp blood </a></li>
    <li><a id="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a id="About">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('.my_links').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName != 'A') return false; //listen for clicks to links only
    GetClick(evt.target.id); //passes ID identifier to your function, e.g. 'Donate'
}, false);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

error prompted in the console

Comment: Then you have no element with the class "my_links".